# Imgur Issue? Cannot see or upload pictures

Tags: bug, status-completed, links, image

I haven't been able to put pictures in my answers, and I cannot see any pictures posted in other people's questions. Is this an issue on my end, or is imgur having issues?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an issue on Imgur's side: see [Is stack.imgur currently down?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313779/is-stack-imgur-currently-down)

> I don't have an update on this other than being more than a little angry with the state of things and that I'm working with Imgur to ensure they get it back online ASAP. – Nick Craver♦

As a workaround, use 1000 words: they render independently of Imgur.

Comment: *"use 1000 words: they render independently of Imgur"* ::chuckles::